# how to use $indexOfArray to return index with other fields in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, indexof

I am trying to fetch result with having index detail by using

> $indexOfArray

It is returning indexof result not other fields

```
        BlogModel.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "$and": [
                    { deleted: { "$eq": 0 } },
                    { status: { "$eq": 0 } }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                name: 1, title: 1, status: 1, order: 1, image: 1, slug: 1, like_by: 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                index: { "$indexOfArray": ["$like_by", new ObjectId('5a8a57c4b9806a6c73785b44')] },
                result: "$name"
            }
        }
    ], (err, blog) => {
            console.log(err || blog);
    })
```

Above query returning only

> { _id: 5c593dfa9382cc068a22ed61, index: 0 }

But i am looking for name, title, status, order, image, slug, like_by to be return with index

Comment: Is there any issue with the below answer?